# Pythagorean triples conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Pythagorian triple is every triple of natural numbers $(x, y, z)$ such that $x, y, z$ are sides of a right triangle, where $z$ is the hypotenuse.

Now, Pythagorean theorem says:
$$x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \tag1$$

If we look just natural solutions to the equation $(1)$, *without geometrical condition* that a right triangle with sides $x, y, z$ do exist, do we have more solutions? And if yes, in which pattern?

Of course, condition that for natural triple satisfying $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ there must exist right triangle with sides $x, y, z$, which is equivalent to add 3 conditions to the $(1)$: (triangle inequality)

0. $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ and
1. $x + y > z$
2. $x + z > y$
3. $y + z > x$

(Because if 1., 2., 3. holds, we can construct right triangle with sides $x, y, z$.)

Comment: What do you mean by "do we have more solutions"

Comment: Let's say we are simply solving equation $x^2 + y^2 = ^2$ in $\mathbb{N}$  for $z < 10 000$, for example. And let's say number of triples satysfying this is $n$. Now, is there any triple $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ of those $n$ triples for which right triangle with sides $x_0, y_0, z_0$ does not exist (cannot be constructible)?

Comment: It can not be possible for a right angle triangle to satisfy $a^2+b^2=c^2$ but not satisfy $a+b>c$ or such triangle inequality? Are you asking for this statement proof

Comment: Yes, that's my question

Comment: The 1.,2.,3. constraints are [true for any triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), they aren't specific to pythagorean ones. If any one of them fails, that's just not a triangle.

Comment: Yes, but *if* 1., 2., 3. works, and (1) works, *then* there exist such triangle. We didn't reduce number of solutions.

Comment: see also [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).

Comment: Conditions 1-3 are trivial, and says that you have a triangle, they are all the triangle inequality. To me it looks like the statement is: «if the pythagorean theorem is true then you have a triangle».

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout, you didn't understand my question at all. Look, $(- 3, - 4, 5)$ is a triple that satisfies $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ but there is no right triangle with sides$- 3, - 4, 5$. Now, since this is obvious, I am asking less obvious question: is there a triple $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ where $x_0, y_0, z_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ that satisfies equation $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ but such that there is no right triangles with sides $x_0, y_0, z_0$ (where $z_0$ would have been hypotenuse).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here $a,$b and $c$ are the base, perpendicular and hypotenuse measures of the right angled triangle.

As per my understanding from OP's comments I need to prove that if $a^2+b^2=c^2$ then prove $a+b>c$, $b+c>a$ and $a+c>b$.

So $a^2+b^2 = c^2$

This implies that $(a+b)^2-2ab=c^2$

See $2ab$ will definitely be positive since $a$,$b$ and $c$ are natural number so adding just $2ab$ to lhs will make lhs $>$ rhs.

$(a+b)^2>c^2$

Rooting both sides

$(a+b)>c$

You might ask why didn't we take the negative case that's because a,b and c are natural numbers and sum of natural number is not negative.

Can you prove the other 2 cases yourself OP?

Comment: Is this answering your question @13b3?

Comment: Yes, this is the proof that problem of finding every single triple of natural numbers $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ that satisfies $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ is equivalent to findind all right triangles with sides natural sides. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One other way to analyse the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$ is to solve it in its quadratic form.

Assuming $x\ne y$ otherwise $z$ would be irrational with factor $\sqrt{2}$.

Lets take $(x<y<z)>0$ without loss of generality and define $x=y-m$ and $z=y+n$ where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers. Giving

$$(y-m)^2+y^2=(y+n)^2\tag{1}$$

with $(z-x)=m+n$, $(z-y)=n$ and $(y-x)=m$

Which on rearrangement becomes

$$y^2-2(m+n)y+(m^2-n^2)=0\tag{2}$$

which can be solved as a quadratic in the usual way, with the result:

$$y=(m+n)+\sqrt{2n(m+n)}$$

[ or alternatively $y=(z-x)+\sqrt{2(z-y)(z-x)}$ ]

With a positive only square root since  $m$ and $n$ are always positive integers.

Therefore

$x=n+\sqrt{2n(m+n)}$, $y= (m+n)+\sqrt{2n(m+n)}$ and $z= (m+2n)+\sqrt{2n(m+n)}$

Then

$(1.)\;\;\;$  $x+y=(m+2n)+2\sqrt{2n(m+n)}>z\;(=(m+2n)+\sqrt{2n(m+n)})$,

$(2.)\;\;\;$  $y+z=(2m+3n)+2\sqrt{2n(m+n)}>x\;(=n+\sqrt{2n(m+n)})$

and

$(3.)\;\;\;$  $x+z=(m+3n)+2\sqrt{2n(m+n)}>y\;(=(m+n)+\sqrt{2n(m+n)})$.

(It is also true that $m\ge n$ or equivalently $3z \ge 5x$, but I'm not sure about the best way to prove that.)

(In the same manner $x^3+y^3=z^3$ can be converted to a cubic equation, $x^4+y^4=z^4$ to a quartic equation, $x^5+y^5=z^5$ to a quintic equation and so on)

Of course you don't need to go this far to prove statements (1.), (2.) and (3.).

Since it can be shown algebraically that $(x+y)^2$ is greater than $z^2$, this immediately implies $(x+y)>z$.

Since we assumed at the outset $z>y$, it trivially follows that $x+z>y$.

Since we assumed at the outset $z>x$, it trivially follows that $y+z>x$.

Recalling the Pythagorean solution $x = a^2-b^2, y = 2ab, z = a^2+b^2$, $y>x$ can't in general be assumed.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question and for this wonderful answer.